# Loop Variable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm using `for()` to loop a function. In this function, you need to have different variable to specific which container will be update.

When loop, the variable will use string+count integer to have different var name. Example: `t=1 > var title1`, `t=2 > var title2` etc.

Example code:-

```
for(t = 1; t <= 5; t++) {
   var title(t) = function(e){}
}
```

If I use var `var title+t = function(e){}`, its not working.

Hope any one can help me on this.

Comment: you can't create variables like that... instead you can use an object and properties like `var obj = {}; for(t = 1; t <= 5; t++) {
   obj['title' + t] = function(e){}
}`

Comment: use Multidimension array for your scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays let you store multiple values and refer to them by an index number.  For example:

```
var title=[];
for (var t=0; t<=4; t++) {
    title[t] = //something
}
```

You can then use an index like `title[2]` to access items in the array. Arrays in Javascript start counting at `0`, so the first item is `title[0]`.